# INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: sharepoint-server, virtual-machine, dmz

my configuration is: classic home network (port-forwarding to one local PC - ok access to web server) - local PC, win 10 with **VirtualBox**, two VMs connected between them (a domain controller and the SharePoint VM) both with a second adapter NAT, OK with internet access - SP 2016 and Win Server 2016 - on host, port forwarding ipaddresshost with port 1025 and allipaddresses (blank) with port 80. **In the VM local network all is fine**. When I try accessing **by host** (with or without internet connection) **I see error INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND**. Googled and found solutions, tried different things but… nothing. Tried by IE 11, Edge and Chrome. Added in guest SP VM's IE trusted sites http://localhost, http://nomeserver, http://ipaddressofguest and http://ipaddressofhost - checked IIS binding, file host and AAM, all is fine in the local VM network. Performed flushdns on host and guest. What's wrong?

Comment: More: once, the localhost was the Default IIS Web Page, worked. Stopped the site, configured the SharePoint as localhost on port 80... works only in local VM network.

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue, from the PC that can't access the site can you ping the site URL or server hostname?  I have a feeling that you can't because the PC that is outside of the VM network does not have DNS entries for the SP site.  Try using a host file entry on the PC that can't connect to the SP site, and see if that will resolve the issue.

Comment: still strange, because the PC outside browse the root of the site and then is (correctly) redirected to the /pages/default.aspx page that gives error